# Split HTML in divs with Javascript/JQuery based on HR tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, split

I want to split articles (= HTML content) that I receive from a webservice in different DIVs, based on a HR tag.

I explain with an example, this is what I receive from the service:

```
<p>This is an article bla bla</p> <hr/> <p>this is the next page of the article blabla ...</p>
```

I want to make, based on the HR-tag:

```
<div><p>This is an article bla bla</p></div>
<div><p>this is the next page of the article blabla ...</p></div>
```

I tried different thinks but is doesn't work. How can I do that with Javascript or JQuery (or with another method ;-))?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use split to create and array and loop through to create the divs.

```
var html = "<p>This is an article bla bla</p> <hr/> <p>this is the next page of the article blabla ...</p>";


$(html.split('<hr/>')).each(function(){
    $('#test').append('<div>'+this+'</div>')
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4tLQg/)

Comment: But you better watch out for spelling variations such as '<hr />', '<HR>', etc. A regular expression accounting for variations would be more robust. See this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40115509/263832

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
var html = '<p>This is an article bla bla</p> <hr/> <p>this is the next page of the article blabla ...</p>'
var htmlarr = html.split('<hr/>');
html = html.replace(/<hr\/>/g,'');
$('body').append(html);
```

This will just remove all the `<hr/>`s then append the remaining contnet to the page.Which I think will achieve what you want without performing a `split`. You could do a split like this -

```
var htmlarr = html.split('<hr/>');
```

Which would leave you with an array containing the two bits of HTML you list in your question. You could add this to your page using -

```
$.each(htmlarr,function (index,value) {
   $('body').append(value); 
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/cCR34/2