# making an array or choice field with a string separated with <br/>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string:

```
Name1<br/>Name2<br/>Name3
```

Im looking to get a choice selector or an array with just the Names as values. I know you can get just the text of a string, but I cant figure out a way separate them. This list changes so I cant hard code the names in.

I cannot find any code nor do I have anything yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split the string based on <br/> tag using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592144/split-the-string-based-on-br-tag-using-jquery)

Comment: No need for jQuery here -- foundation JavaScript works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the split function:

```
var text = "Name1<br/>Name2<br/>Name3";
var list = text.split("<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily accomplished using JavaScript built-in [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```
var input_s = "Name1<br />Name2<br />Name3";
var input_r = input_s.split("<br />");
```